# Arduino bluetooth on android

Tags: android, bluetooth, controls, arduino

My application :
  /** 
 * Connect bluetooth smarphone. 
 * auto on bluetooth and button turn off bluetooth 
 */

```
package com.Iris;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import java.util.Set;




public class IrisActivity extends Activity  
{
Button button1;
// button Off bluettooch
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
// ac
bluetoothAdapter.enable();

Toast.makeText(IrisActivity.this, "Bluetooth Activé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Set<BluetoothDevice> devices;
devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
for (BluetoothDevice blueDevice : devices) 
{
Toast.makeText(IrisActivity.this, "Réseau : " + blueDevice.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
public void onClick(View v) 
{
bluetoothAdapter.disable();
Toast.makeText(IrisActivity.this, "Bluetooth Désactivé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});

}
```

My application is Good, but I want connect at "blueDevice.getName"  and send ASCI letter "H" with my application

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [BluetoothChat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) sample. Basically, you'll need to do the following on transmit side:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = blueDevice.connect();
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write("H");
```

You'll need a server socket on the receive side shown in sample.